# SwiftUI view is adjusting itself near the safe area

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm having an issue while moving a view that contains a SwiftUI view near the edges of the screen. The SwiftUI view moves itself to avoid being blocked by the safe area insets

[image]

I'm using UIKit to handle dragging the view via `UIHostingController` and a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. Here's the code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var contentView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let contentVc = UIHostingController(rootView: Content())
        addChild(contentVc)
        contentView = contentVc.view
        let contentHeight = contentView.sizeThatFits(view.bounds.size).height
        contentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: view.bounds.width, height: contentHeight)
        view.addSubview(contentView)
        contentVc.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        let drag = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(drag(_:)))
        contentView.addGestureRecognizer(drag)
        
        view.backgroundColor = .orange
    }
    
    var startingPoint = CGPoint.zero
    @objc func drag(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            startingPoint = contentView.frame.origin
        case .changed:
            let location = gesture.translation(in: view)
            contentView.frame.origin.y = startingPoint.y + location.y
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}


import SwiftUI

struct Content: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<10) { i in
                Text(String(i))
            }
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
        .padding(.vertical, 32)
        
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

What I'm expecting is the blue view to not to adjust itself vertically (in the preview the blue view's top padding is shrinking)

Comment: It was always like that you are expecting the thing that was not even a thing from beginning. That modifier modifies view when the view hits safeArea.

Comment: @swiftPunk Okay, so that explains why when I drag the view into the safeArea the blue extends bc it's ignoring the safe area. Am I understanding that right?

Comment: That is correct. @ErickES7

Comment: Okay, so ignoreSafeArea is not the modifier to use to fix this. I've the title to not include ignoresSafeArea not working

Comment: I am not sure if you need that modifier on your SwiftUI view! why would you need it there? I would delete it!

Comment: Okay. Removing the modifier still produces the issue if the blue box is cut off at the bottom of the screen

Comment: @ErickES7 This is a strange issue, seems like a bug. However - this is also quite a weird mix of SwiftUI & UIKit - you can make the gesture in SwiftUI, and handle all that there instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 ways for solving this issue:

### Way1: Using UIKit Gesture!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var contentView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let contentVc = UIHostingController(rootView: Content())
        addChild(contentVc)
        contentView = contentVc.view
        let contentHeight = contentView.sizeThatFits(view.bounds.size).height
        contentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: view.bounds.width, height: contentHeight)
        contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.addSubview(contentView)
        contentVc.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        let drag = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(drag(_:)))
        contentView.addGestureRecognizer(drag)
        
        view.backgroundColor = .orange
    }
    
    var startingPoint = CGPoint.zero
    @objc func drag(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            startingPoint = contentView.frame.origin
        case .changed:
            let location = gesture.translation(in: view)
            contentView.frame.origin.y = startingPoint.y + location.y
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}


import SwiftUI

struct Content: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<10) { i in
                Text(String(i))
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.blue)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.white)

    }
}
```

### Way2: Using SwiftUI Gesture!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var contentView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let contentVc = UIHostingController(rootView: Content())
        addChild(contentVc)
        contentView = contentVc.view
        contentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)
        contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.addSubview(contentView)
        contentVc.didMove(toParent: self)

        view.backgroundColor = .orange
    }

}


struct Content: View {

    @State private var offset: CGFloat = .zero
    @State private var lastOffset: CGFloat = .zero

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<10) { i in
                Text(String(i))
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.blue)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.white)
        .offset(y: offset)
        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: .zero, coordinateSpace: .local).onChanged { value in

            offset = lastOffset + value.translation.height

        }
        .onEnded { value in
            lastOffset = lastOffset + value.translation.height
            offset = lastOffset
        })

    }
}
```